# React native expo apk size

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing my react native apk via Expo. exp start and then exp build:android in cmd. My apk size is 27MB when I download it to phone, but when APK is installed it is 50MB. How is this possible? Can I reduce apk size?

Please help me.

Comment: The fact that installed apk size is way more than the 'not installed' apk is completely fine, that is how android works, nothing is wrong with your code. But if the initial 27MB is larger than what you want you can start by reading these pages https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code and https://medium.com/exploring-code/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e . Also try to remove large image assets from your apk

Comment: Regarding the 27KB, the Expo guys are working on reducing it, not sure when it will be available.